Is it going to give me issues if I rig my character without joining it? And if so how do I keep all my pieces together?
Sorta brand new to blender, please be nice! I really want to be making low poly characters with segmented limbs in order for me to switch them out easily. I have never done it this way and am wondering how this works?
Am I forced to join all the segments before making the IK Rig or is there some other way that I can keep them all together without joining while animating?
I know that there is probably a right and wrong way to go about this and I want to do it the right way, but I can't find much documentation on how to do this. I want to add certain modifiers to the head and hands to make them damp track the camera like DOOM sprites (attached photo). I feel like I can't do that if all the pieces are joined
Sorry if this is a lot! Let me know if I can describe anything more thoroughly! Thank u stack exchange.


General case
There are caveats in having one or multiple mesh objects for a rigged character.

Ease of weight paint. Although Blender supports multi-object editing since years, it's (a bit) harder to manage on multiple objects than a single object.
Performance optimization. May it be Blender or other softwares, even game engines, having one mesh object vs several is usually simpler to optimize for rendering performance as it requires fewer draw calls. Though admittedly, in your case it's not a dozen objects that will take a hit in your performances, unless you are running on a potato.
Safer exports When it comes to exporting, such as in FBX, having a single mesh object reduces complexity and potential issues during the export and import processes, making it easier to manage and animate. Although it doesn't mean that multi-objects will cause issues.
Versatility if you don't need to export to other softwares or are able to do so as a geometry cache (alembic or usd), having multiple objects give you quite some flexibility: being able to use different subdivision levels on each one of them, using booleans, ...


Particular case

I want to add certain modifiers to the head and hands to make them damp track the camera like DOOM sprites (attached photo). I feel like I can't do that if all the pieces are joined

I don't know which modifiers you think of exactly. Damp track is a constraint, and bones have bone constraints. So you could use either. If you intend to export, I would stick to bone constraints, as they can be baked into keyframes and exported as a single animation data block with all your armature's bones. Whereas having animation on both your armature bones and your objects would lead to having to export one animation data block per object, and that's annoying to handle externally.
